# Rails 4 - Css bootstrap not working in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

In development in the file application.html.erb i have the line :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

It works on development but not in production. 
What's wrong?

For more details, you can test it yourself with my appplication deployed with Heroku : https://library-online-duofer.herokuapp.com and see the code with : https://github.com/chtrang/Duong_Fernandez.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: are you sure its not working? I can see the page rendered with the styles

Comment: Ah, I see this error in the console: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://library-online-duofer.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: make the cdn URL to be https and you should be fine..

Comment: @droidbot: Thank you for your anwer. Very helpful!

Comment: great if you can mark that as an answer that solved your problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarise my comment: Your production environment is in https, while the CDN is http. Change the CDN url to be https and the problem will be sorted.